# Where to add error handling when calling an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am using an async `window.fetch` call which returns a promise. To resolve the result I put my handler in the `then()` part of that promise.

The docs for `async await` suggest using `try catch` to catch errors. But  a Promise has a `reject` and a `catch()` function as well...

It's not clear to me which of these three I have to use to catch a failed loading attempt from the `fetch` call. I also don't see the difference between a rejected Promise and just a failed fetch that is caught with `fetch(url).then().catch()`.

My only requirement is that the `fetch` call is inside its own function that I can call from anywhere.

```
// CALLING THE LOADDATA FUNCTION
loadData().then(res => {
         console.log("success")
      }, err => {
         console.log("rejected!")
      }).catch(e => {
         console.log("error is " + e);
      })

// ASYNC LOADDATA
async function loadData() {
    try{
        const response = await fetch('./data.json');
        return await response.json();
    } 
    catch(e) {
        console.log("nope!")
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch in await` what should that be?

Comment: you can use `.catch()` after `.then()` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but you are probably getting downvoted for a couple reasons.  1) You ask "What is the best", so people will flag this as opinion based.  2) You are asking multiple questions.  You might try refining the wording a bit to avoid these things.

Comment: a rejected promise isn't necessarily an promise with an exception.

Comment: I agree with @ScottBeeson . Which error can be handled at which step in a promise/async flow is a bit confusing.

Comment: @ScottBeeson OK I tried to rephrase the question... I can't help the confused tone though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best point to catch errors?

You should handle errors at the place where the data is required, so where the failure occurs and more importantly where you can really handle it. That means that you should inform the user about the error or retry or whatever.
In your case the error handler silences all errors and cannot really handle them, which makes it unneccessary to use `Promise.catch` as the promise will be never rejected.
 So your loadData function should not handle the error at all but pass it to the higher level scope:

```
 async function loadData(){ 
   return (await fetch('./data.json')).json();
 }
```

Now you can handle the error using `then`:

```
 loadData().then(
  /*success*/ (data) => console.log(data),
  /*failure*/ (err) => console.error(err)
 );
```

Or using async / await :

```
 (async function(){
    try {
      console.log( await loadData() );
    } catch(e){
      console.error(e);
   }
})()
```

> What's the difference between a rejected promise, a catch() in the promise, and a catch in await?

When a promise is rejected, it calls the handler passed to `catch` or the second parameter of `then`.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how this `async` syntax got to be such a mess with all these different approaches!